# When making a movie on a book, is the author of the book present?

Tags: book-adaptation

I have always wondered if the author of a book is present when making a movie. For example, the new movie Scorch Trials that just came out is so much different from the book, that it is hard to believe that the author is there and verifying every move of their published book. Are the authors there and verifying every move? Do they help and approve the design of a movie poster?

Comment: Might have been disturbing if they had Tolkien along at the filming of his books.  Quite a few authors take exception to the ruin of their books by film makers.  King hated The Shining;  Anne Rice says Queen of the Damned has nothing to do with her book; EL Travers didn't like Mary Poppins and there are many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to give a percentage of yes vs no. Often, a company buys the rights to a book completely, and the author gets a writing credit. Maybe a writing consultation. But they rarely get a veto over the directors vision.

Comment: so Scorch trials for example, could be totally against the authors will and may just have the same basics such as the characters but the rest is the directors vision?

Comment: @anonymous see http://www.thecredits.org/2015/09/talking-to-author-james-dashner-about-maze-runner-the-scorch-trials/ for scorch in particular. James trusted the film makers changes cause they know more about films.

Comment: that makes a lot more sense. I wouldn't have taken out the tunnel scene in though like the book has after escaping through the portal and I definitely wouldn't have killed any other characters